# Post-hoc tests for lmer three-way interaction

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, interaction, lsmeans

I am trying to perform post-hoc tests on a linear mixed-effect model with a significant three-way interaction, whereby two of the two-way interactions are significant. There are two 2-level factors and one continious variable in the three way interaction, plus two covariates and a random intercept. The first factor is time, with two timepoints. The model looks like this:

```
lmer(DV ~ Fact1_Time * Fact2_Condition * Cont1 + Age + Sex + (1|ID), data)
```

I have attempted to run post-hoc tests using the emmeans function, but the results seem wrong. How would I perform post hoc tests on significant two way interactions between `Fact1_Time  * Fact2_Condition` and `Fact2_Condition * Cont1`? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question doesn't indicate what "seemed wrong" about what you attempted, or indeed about what you tried to do. I'd suggest looking at `vignette("interactions")` which gives several examples. Typically, with interactions of factors you may want to use 'by' variables or perhaps compute interaction contrasts. With a factor and a covariate, the 'emtrends` function may be used to estimate slopes,then you can use `pairs()` to compare them.

Answer (score 1):

Regression analyses do not require post-hoc tests per se. This is mostly an ANOVA thing where you start with the model F-test and then follow up with post-hoc tests for effects of specific factors. In regression, you still have a model F-test, and then you interpret your Beta coefficients. All beta coefficients alone should be sufficient to understand interactions in regression. Though, three way interactions can be a lot to get ones head around.  Often the suggested approach for interpreting/reporting interactions in regression is to show them visually, and the Beta coefficients are sufficient information to show all the potential differences.